# Changing the player's position in Update() or FixedUpdate() method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I've a case that when the player is touching the collider of a specific *GameObject* and the player press the X key I want to change his position to the position of another *GameObject*.

To do that I use the following code

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
    {
        // Check Colliders collition
        // End of Check Colliders collition

        var playerRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        playerRigidBody.position = AnotherObject.transform.position;
    }
}
```

I've realized that very often when I press the X key the player don't change his position to the position of the other *GameObject*. However if I move the code to the *Update()* method it works as expected (with no delay).

But I've read in the official documentation and in a lot of blogs that the code related to physics and Rigidbodies must be put in the *FixedUpdate* instead of Update

So the question is the following:

For this case putting the code in the *Update()* method is not recommended? (Note that I'm not using forces nor torques)

If it's not recommended then how can I assure that every time the player press the X key he will change his position to the other *GameObject* position in *FixedUpdate()*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if you want a smooth movement you should rather use [`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) in `FixedUpdate` otherwise everything regarding Physics (so also RigidBody) you should always do in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) (as explained in the API there as well).

---

You should however catch the `GetKeyDown` in `Update` and **split those two things**:

```
bool wasClicked;
RigidBody playerRigidBody;

void Start()
{
    // do this only once!
    playerRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    // Catch user input here

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
    {
        wasClicked = true;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Handle physics here

    if(!wasClicked) return;

    playerRigidBody.position = AnotherObject.transform.position;

    wasClicked = false;
}
```

Comment: Note that for *teleportation* (*`if the player is touching the collider of a specific GameObject and the player press the X key I want to change his position to the position of another GameObject`*) MovePosition isn't desired.

Comment: @Draco18s thank you for your help. I had a bug that I was fighting for a week. The solution is to split the code in both method *Update()* and *FixedUpdate().* Thank you again!

Comment: @vcRobe Oh, no doubt. Just that sometimes you DO want to teleport the player and using MovePosition won't work in that case!

Comment: Just added the `MovePosition` as an additional general comment. As you can see in the code example I used `rigidbody.position` anyway ;)

Comment: Sorry, in the previous comment I was thanking to @derHugo. Anyways Draco18s thank you for the comment. Before the doubt about the methods *Update()* and *FixedUpdate()* I spent some hours guessing why the player didn't teleport to the expected position and it was because I used *RidigBody2D.MovePosition()* instead of *RigidBody2D.position* but I fixed it because the distance I was teleporting the player in the tests was huge and clearly the final position of the player was ALWAYS wrong. Thank you guys!

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html -> I can't believe in *their own sample*, in `FixedUpdate()` they use `deltaTime` instead of `fixedDeltaTime`. Even their examples are bad coding. And the `m_` syntax shows it's a C++ guy, not an actual C# guy...

Comment: @OlivierPons the `m_` syntax is also applied to all `c#` in Unity which is a convention and fine ;) But yeah as the backend is `c++` and the `c#` just a dev layer on top of it lots of things have been adopted ^^ Now to `deltaTime` please read the doc of [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) => it returns correctly also within `FixedUpdate` that's why they even encouraged to simply always use `deltaTime`

Comment: @derHugo You're right on every point, thanks for the explanation. They've changed this behavior deltaTime <> fixedDeltaTime. They should either remove fixedDeltaTime / or / add a warning (not hard to do in C#).