# Jumping Is Not Working As Expected Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am trying to figure out why my jumping is inconsistent. I've looked at many StackOverflow questions and I still can't find a solution. If someone could help that would be amazing! :D

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BallMovement : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;

private Rigidbody rb;

void Start ()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    Camera mainCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("8BallCamera").GetComponent<Camera>() as Camera;
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    Vector3 movement = mainCamera.transform.forward * moveVertical * 30;
    rb.AddForce (movement * speed);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
        rb.AddForce(0,2f,0, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I think input is read in Update instead of FixedUpdate, so depending on your framerate, it's possible to get the jump to happen either multiple times per input, have it not happen at all for all inputs, or a mix of both if your framerate varies. If you read your input in Update, it should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank for the comment. How exactly do i read input instead of my way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the player's position in Update() or FixedUpdate() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165962/changing-the-players-position-in-update-or-fixedupdate-method)

Comment: Like I said @derHugo I already tried other solutions.This is a different issue. Advice was given to me to move from Update() to FixedUpdate() but the solution wasn't that. It was adding a cooldown timer that fixed it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When asking a question, try to be more detailed on the facts of the issue, as phrases like "not working as expected" and "jumping is inconsistent" is pretty subjective, and could mean something different depending who reads it :)

I tried out the code on my machine, and found that sometimes pressing the space bar would not initiate the jump. No other issues seemed to arise (although you may want to place in a cooldown for your jump later on).

The issue was with your jump codes being in **FixedUpdate()**. **FixedUpdate()** seems to run before **Update()**, but it's not always called. This is why the space input was sometimes unnoticed.

Placing it inside **Update()** will fix the issue.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BallMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Camera mainCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("8BallCamera").GetComponent<Camera>() as Camera;
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = mainCamera.transform.forward * moveVertical * 30;
        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 2f, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you recommend doing a cool down? I tried new WaitForSeconds(1); but it didnt work :(

Comment: Declare a float variable with the desired cooldown (let's say 1.5f).
Declare another float variable, say "CooldownFinishedTime".

Inside the if statement code, set CooldownFinishedTime to Time.time (which is the time in seconds  since the start of the game) + the cooldown.
For the if statement conditions, also add in "&& Time.time > CooldownFinishedTime". This would mean that you can jump only if the space bar is pressed and the cooldown has finished.

Comment: AWESOME! That did it! Any tips on making the jump so it's not so fast? Thanks again!!

Comment: @BenPalladino You need to `*` by the deltaTime.

Comment: @penleychan will that make him jump slower? if so where do i put that?

Comment: `AddForce` and anything related to Physics should be used in `FixedUpdate` though! (also see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57166114/7111561))